# How to reject a job offer out of moral reasons without sounding self righteous

Tags: rejection

I received a great opportunity through a personal contact to work in an industry that I am ethically against.

The working conditions are exactly what I am interested in and I would like my contact to think of me if a similar opportunity comes his way again.

I do not believe that morals are universal and accept that other people live by different values. So I don't want my rejection to sound like I disapprove of anyone working in that industry. I only want to convey that it is not a good fit for me personally.

Comment: Did you interview for the position? When did you realize you had a moral objection to their business?

Comment: You kind of answered your own question. You definitely don't want to get into the details of why you don't approve of them. If you are true to your values, you won't agonize at all about your decision no matter how lucrative it looks. Your contact may already suspect that a number of candidates may have a similar view as you.

Comment: you can`t convey any details past "its not a good fit for me" to your personal contact without sounding preachy.
Your question is full of it.
 Even at that, be ready to loose your personal contact. Private opportunity often is his head on the line to put you through the layers to the top candidate. you falling out, is a hit for him

Comment: In short you wasted someone's time.  If you got a job **offer**, you wasted many someones.

Answer (score 5):

Just tell your friend it's the sort of position you're interested in for the future, just not that particular opportunity.

No need to go into high horse detail.